# Employee home OSX laptop was stolen. How can I determine if the laptop was encrypted?

Tags: macos, filevault

A non technical employee has had an OSX laptop stolen.

1) What technical approaches (iCloud verification)
2) What Questions should I ask the user to determine if the laptop was encrypted. (boot up time)

**Background**

I know that any laptop with Yosemite installed would have encryption enabled by default, but I want to confirm if that "default checkbox" was unchecked during initialization or upgrade.

[image]

Above, there seems to be an iCloud integration here that might mean I can inspect a user's iCloud account for that device being encrypted.  Or perhaps I can ask Apple Support for this information (or the user themselves can inquire at our direction)

Comment: I'm thinking your best bet is to have the user call Apple at your direction and relay the info back to you. Either that or have them answer the security questions and pass the phone off to you (or your staff).

Comment: well why do you not determine the year which then will give you the the potential OS version....if the user is as nontechnical as it seems you might be implying then they would not have touched the boxes, if they did then they should know enough to answer the question them self?